# Awk to split input a tab-delimited file using multiple delimiters in the same field

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk` to split the `file`, skipping the header, into either an `8-column` or `6-column` output. I am not sure if I did the split correct though as I need to split `$2` first by the `:` then by the `-`. The desired output of each `awk` is below as one or the other is used depending on the situation. Thank you :).

**file** 'tab-delimited`

```
Gene    Position    Strand
SMARCB1 22:24133967-24133967    +
RB1 13:49037865-49037865    -
SMARCB1 22:24176357-24176357    +
```

**awk**

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" 'NR>1{split($2,a,":"); print a[1],a[2],a[3],"chr"$2,"0",$3,"GENE_ID="$1}'
```

**8-column desired output** `tab-delimited`

```
chr22   24133967    24133967    chr22:24133967-24133967 0   +   .   GENE_ID=SMARCB1
chr13   49037865    49037865    chr13:49037865-49037865 0   -   .   GENE_ID=RB1
chr22   24176357    24176357    chr22:24176357-24176357 0   +   .   GENE_ID=SMARCB1
```

**awk**

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" 'NR>1{split($2,a,":"); print a[1],a[2],a[3],"chr"$2,".",$1,}'
```

**6-column desired output** `tab-delimited`

```
chr22   24133967    24133967    chr22:24133967-24133967 .   SMARCB1
chr13   49037865    49037865    chr13:49037865-49037865 .   RB1
chr22   24176357    24176357    chr22:24176357-24176357 .   SMARCB1
```

Comment: You should know about creating an MCVE ([MCVE]) by now, which requires both input data and actual and expected output.  Do the Awk scripts produce the data you want?  If so, they're probably correct, but if they were correct, you probably wouldn't be asking the question.  That leads us to suppose you want something different as output, but we can't easily guess what you want.

Comment: please update your Q to show your required output. Do you want a 8 col or 6 col output (or both?). Good

Comment: Each output is a seperate `awk`, as it is situational what type I will use... Thank you :)

Comment: I added details to the post and upon executing the `awk` I find it runs but did not do the split correctly. The desired output depends on what the software being used requires, as sometimes it is `6-column` other times it is `8-column`. Thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extended approach:

For ***6***-column output:

```
awk -v c=6 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }NR>1{ split($2,a,":|-"); k="chr"; 
             printf("%s\t%d\t%d\t%s\t",k a[1],a[2],a[3],k $2); 
             if (c==6) print ".",$1; else print "0",$3,".","GENE_ID="$1 }' file
```

The output:

```
chr22   24133967    24133967    chr22:24133967-24133967 .   SMARCB1
chr13   49037865    49037865    chr13:49037865-49037865 .   RB1
chr22   24176357    24176357    chr22:24176357-24176357 .   SMARCB1
```

---

For ***8***-column output (via passing `-v c=<number>` (column) variable):

```
awk -v c=8 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }NR>1{ split($2,a,":|-"); k="chr"; 
             printf("%s\t%d\t%d\t%s\t",k a[1],a[2],a[3],k $2); 
             if (c==6) print ".",$1; else print "0",$3,".","GENE_ID="$1 }' file
```

The output:

```
chr22   24133967    24133967    chr22:24133967-24133967 0   +   .   GENE_ID=SMARCB1
chr13   49037865    49037865    chr13:49037865-49037865 0   -   .   GENE_ID=RB1
chr22   24176357    24176357    chr22:24176357-24176357 0   +   .   GENE_ID=SMARCB1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)